# How to print ActiveView to printer in ArcEngine 10

Tags: arcgis-engine, c#

I am following a printing tutorial, but it's not working.

The tutorial is here: 
http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/NET/ViewCodePages/025b5da7-9b10-4623-a51e-c038c348ce29.PrintActiveViewCS_NetPrintActiveViewCS_Net.cs.htm

Maybe printing in ArcEngine 10 is different.  The initial problem is that the PageLayout is null.

```
//I tried this like in the sample
docPaper.Orientation = m_hookHelper.PageLayout.Page.Orientation;

//Then I tried passing in my own ActiveView obj and casting to PageLayout
 IPageLayout pageLayout = docActiveView as IPageLayout;
```

But in both cases they are null.

Does anyone have a good link for printing in ArcEngine 10?

Comment: Are you using the pagelayout control?

Comment: @Kirk Kuykendall No, I don't know anything about that.  I tried adding esriControlCommands.ControlsPageLayoutToolbar to my toolbar but it was inactive.  So I'm not really clear on what it's supposed to do, any links are appreciated.

Comment: If you want to print a nice looking map, I'd recommend using the pagelayoutcontrol instead of the mapcontrol. http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000497000000

Answer (score 1):

The ActiveView can be either a Map or a Pagelayout if you check the sample you see that they are checking if the ActiveView is a pagelayout or not at several places. The reason for this is to make it would work in both cases. If you customizing the code and are only interested in printing a MapControl, you should look only on the parts of the code where the ActiveView is not a pagelayout.